Create email thread in outlook using Java & JCOB library
I have a desktop application developed in Java, I am creating an email with HTML body then saving it as "JacobEmail.msg", and immediately open that email file in Outlook application using JACOB.
Here is the code:
 void createEmail(String subject, String recipientTo, String recipientCC, String recipientBCC, String body, String[] attachments) {

            Dispatch mail = Dispatch.call(oOutlook, "CreateItem", email).toDispatch();

            Dispatch.put(mail, "Subject", subject);
            Dispatch.put(mail, "To", recipientTo);
            Dispatch.put(mail, "CC", recipientCC);
            Dispatch.put(mail, "BCC", recipientBCC);
            Dispatch.put(mail, "HTMLBody", body);

            Dispatch.call(mail, "SaveAs","D:\\JacobEmail.msg");

            Dispatch.call(mail, "Display");
        }

So far, it works fine but..
The question is that I want to create email threads using the same approach, and append new email to the conversation based on the certain criterias i.e email with same CC or To should be in a thread (reply to previous email).
How to achieve that?
So far I have tried:
First: Retrieved the ID of previous email.
String previousEmailId= Dispatch.get(mailItem, "EntryID").getString();


Second: Retrieved the previous email by id.
Dispatch originalMail = Dispatch.call(namespace, "GetItemFromID", previousEmailId).toDispatch();`


Third: Opened the previous email (Original email which we are intended to reply to).
Dispatch.call(originalMail, "Display");

Note: All the above steps worked and I could get the previous email using id.
Fourth: Tried to reply to the previousEmail (originalMail ).
Dispatch replyMail = Dispatch.call(originalMail, "ReplyAll").toDispatch();

The error that I am getting is:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Invoke of: ReplyAll
Source: Microsoft Outlook
Description: Could not send the message.

I have searched for a while but could not find a suitable solution for this problem, your help & suggestions will be highly appreciated.
